# JSXGraph 0.99.7 union of curves

Tags: stack, moodle, jsxgraph

Because of the Moodle-STACK environment I am currently limited to JSXGraph 0.99.7. Is there a way to get the union of two curves given by coordinate vectors (polygons) in that version?

In 1.2.1 I do this using Clip.union(), which works fine in [jsfiddle (not exactly a minimum working example)](https://jsfiddle.net/mkraska/35yqj9wb/337/) but not in STACK.

```
      this.b = board.create('curve', JXG.Math.Clip.union( bneu, this.b, board), 
    {opacity: true, fillcolor:'lightgray', strokeWidth: normalStyle.strokeWidth, 
     strokeColor: normalStyle.strokeColor});
```

Answer (score 0):

In 0.99.7 you have to do the union by hand. As long as the shapes are not overlapping this might be doable without too much work. Define a curve and set its
`updataDataArray` method:

```
c = board.create('curve', [[], []]);
c.updateDataArray = function() {
    this.dataX = [];
    this.dataY = [];
    // copy now the coordinates of the polygons / curves into
    // these arrays.
};
board.update();
```

You can access the coordinates of the polygon vertices by

```
polygon.vertices[i].X();
polygon.vertices[i].Y();
```

Attention: the last vertex is a copy of the first vertex, to make the polygon a closed curve.

The coordinates of a curve can be accessed by

```
curve.points[i].usrCoords[1]; // x-coordinate
curve.points[i].usrCoords[2]; // y-coordinate
```

The curve path can be interrupted by adding `NaN`s:

```
this.dataX.push(NaN);
this.dataY.push(NaN);
```

Hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I already wondered, why I get a NaN in the curve data arrays for disjoint curves in 1.2.1. I will just not execute the union in 0.99.7, because there are good chances for STACK to get updated soon.